# Gerrit ssh: fatal: "-is:wip" is not a valid option

Tags: ssh, gerrit

I'm trying to make a query request using gerrit ssh command tool.

I want to exclude some parts of a query.

In both Gerrit UI and REST API this could be done by addint `"-"`, e.g.:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/-is:wip

And [the documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html) shows such examples:
[image]

But when I try to do this using ssh:

`ssh -p 29418 gerrit gerrit query --format json -is:wip`
I'm getting an error:

`fatal: "-is:wip" is not a valid option`

What I tried:

- `'-is:wip'`
- `"-is:wip"`
- `'"-is:wip"'`
- `'\-is:wip'`
- `'"\-is:wip"'`
- `\-is:wip`
- `'"\\-is:wip'`
  and so on

Nothing works.

But if I won't use `"-"`, then query works fine:
`ssh -p 29418 gerrit gerrit query --format json status:wip`

How can I search for what I want in Gerrit via ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh -p 29418 gerrit gerrit query --format json NOT is:wip
```

Comment: I should've [read the docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#_negation) more accurately. Thanks!

Comment: Works with the `age` operator as well. Tried `NOT age:'1d'` instead of `-age:'1d'`and the error was gone!